# Virtuemart preset product fields in admin

Tags: php, html, virtuemart

If you need to add a product in virtuemart I only use 25% of the products fields. I wish to preset the input fields so I don't have to fill in all the fields. The problem is that the value of the input is a php-code to insert it into the database.

```
<input type="text" class="inputbox"  name="product_name" value="<?php echo shopMakeHtmlSafe( $db->sf("product_name")); ?>" size="32" maxlength="255" />
```

**Is there a way to echo a standard value in the input fields? Without distrubing the connection or make it bug.**

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just create one product manually, make it a "template product" (i.e. fields are prefilled as you want them), and then use the clone product feature?

In the Virtuemart backend, go to Products -> List Products, look next to the trashcan icon and you should see a "Clone Product" icon